# Use multiple/different MongoTemplates with same Respository class

Tags: spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate, mongorepository

I have a collection on three different mongo databases(same schema). So I have created a Repository for this. But is it possible that i can use different mongoTemplates(one for three different databases) but same repository class.

I can create three different repository classes(one for each database), But I don't want to do this because the schema is the same on all three.

Thanks