# spring-data-mongodb to write to multiple db's

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I want a single mongo template to write to two different mongo clusters. And those two clusters cannot be replica sets, because each of them has its own set of configurations. Is it possible ? I am using repositories to store data and uses spring data mongodb module as a driver. Spring mongo db version spring-data-mongodb (1.9.1.RELEASE) and mongo-java-driver 3.3.0.

Comment: You can't configure multiple MongoDB database for a sigle MongoDB template. Please take a look to [MongoTemplate API Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html).

Comment: I have a similar question which is not answered. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38265818/use-multiple-mongotemplates-with-same-respository-class

Comment: Can I write a wrapper template wrapping all the mongo templates of different clusters and then use it to do the operations?